# Activity -> AsyncTask -> BroadcastReceiver -> Update UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am starting an `AsyncTask` from an `Activity`. When, the `AsyncTask` completes its execution I need to send a broadcast which needs to call `Activity` method to update the UI.
Any good approach to achieve this.

Comment: I think, It's better to use Observer pattern to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity` then it has access to any member variables and your `Activity` methods. If it isn't then you can simply pass variables to its constructor or even a reference to the `Activity` to call `Activity` methods from `onPostExecute()`. Without any code its hard to say much else.

To pass an instance of your `Activity` and use its methods if its a separate class then you can create a constructor and do something like

```
    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...>  // add your params
{
    private MyActivity activty;

    public MyTask (MyActivity act)
    {
        this.activty = activty;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and in `onPostExecute()` add something like

```
activity.myMethod();
```

and call the task like

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(this); // pass a reference of the activity
task.execute();  // add params if needed
```

If the `AsyncTask` is a separate file from the `Activity` then you can [see this answer on how to use an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) for a `callback`

Answer (score 3):

Please use Interface.

```
interface INotifyChange {
    void notifyChange(); // You can use params to transfer data :D
}
```

In **Activity** you should implements this **interface**.

```
YourActivity  extends Activity implements INotifyChange {

    @Override
    public void notifyChange() {
        // Right here, you can Update UI.
    }
}
```

When you create new instance of **AsyncTask**

Example:

```
YourAsyncTask mTask = new YourAsyncTask(this); // You put INotifyChange
```

In **YourAsyncTask**

```
private INotifyChange iNotifyChange;
public YourAsyncTask(INotifyChange iNotifyChange) {
    this.iNotifyChange = iNotifyChange;
}
```

// When you complete doInBackground or anywhere you want to Update UI please use **iNotifyChange.notifyChange()**

Example:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(ResultType mResult) {
    iNotifyChange.notifyChange();
}
```

By this way I often use to update progress bar. In this case, I use parameter in my method:

Example:

```
iNotifyChange.notify(progress);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered overwriting the onPostExecute() method of the AsyncTask to update the UI? Try something like this:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>(imageView)
{
    private ImageView imageView;

    public AsyncTask(ImageView imageView)
    {
         this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground (String... params)
    {
        if(params.length > 0)
        {
            String filePath = params[0];

            // Load Bitmap from file

            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
       imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
task.execute(filePath);
```