# Inner class can access but not update values - AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am trying to unzip a folder using Android's `AsyncTask`. The class (called Decompress) is an inner class of `Unzip` where Unzip itself is a non-Activity class. The pseudo-code is:

```
public class Unzip {  
  private String index;  
  private String unzipDest;    //destination file for storing folder.
  private Activity activity;
  private boolean result;      //result of decompress.

  public void unzip(String loc) {

    Decompress workThread = new Decompress(loc, activity);
    workThread.execute();  
    if(unzip operation was successful) {
      display(index);
  }

  //Class Decompress:
class Decompress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = null;
        private Context mContext;
                private String loc;
        private int nEntries;
        private int entriesUnzipped;

        public Decompress(String location, Context c) {
                        loc = location;
            mContext = c;
            nEntries = 0;
            entriesUnzipped = 0;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Exiting decompress constructor.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Inside onPreExecute.");
            pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pd.setTitle("Unzipping folder.");
            pd.setMessage("Unzip in progress.");
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Showing dialog and exiting.");
            pd.show();
        }

               @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                       //unzip operation goes here.
                       unzipDest = something;  //unzip destination is set here.

                       if(unzip operation is successful) {
                          result = true;
                          index = url pointing to location of unzipped folder.
                       } else {
                         result = false;
                       }
                }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result) {
                if(pd != null) {
                    pd.setTitle("Success");
                    pd.setMessage("folder is now ready for use.");
                    pd.show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                    pd = null;
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Unzipped.");

                    index = unzipDest + "/someURL";
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "index present in: " + index);
                }
            } else {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Failure", "Cannot unzip.");
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Problems I am facing:
1. The value of `unzipDest` and `index`, updated in `doInBackground`, remain null to `Unzip` and all its objects. How can I ensure that the values remain updated?
2. I know that doInBackground occurs in a thread separate from the main UI thread. Does that mean that any values updated in the new thread will be lost once that thread returns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How can I ensure that the values remain updated?

They will be updated since they are member variables. However, since `AsyncTask` is asynchrounous, they might not be updated yet when you check them. You can use an `interface` to create a callback when these values are updated. [This SO answer covers how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

> Does that mean that any values updated in the new thread will be lost once that thread returns?

No they shouldn't be "lost". They probably just haven't been changed in the `AsyncTask` when you check them.

Since this isn't your actual code I can't see when you are trying to access them but you can use the `interface` method or call the functions that need these values in `onPostExecute()`. You also can do a `null` check before trying to access them. It just depends on the functionality and flow that you need as to which is the best way. Hope that helps.

**Edit**

In the answer I linked to, you tell the `Activity` that you will use that `interface` and override its method(s) with `implements AsyncResponse` in your `Activity` declaration after creating the separate `interface class`

```
public class MainActivity implements AsyncResponse{
```

then, in your `Activity` still, you override the method you declared in that class (`void processFinish(String output);`)

```
@Override
 void processFinish(String output){  // using same params as onPostExecute()
 //this you will received result fired from async class of onPostExecute(result) method.
   }
```

then this is called in `onPostExecute()` when the listener sees that it is done with `delegate.processFinish(result);` `delegate` is an instance of `AsyncResponse` (your interface class)

```
    public class AasyncTask extends AsyncTask{
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.processFinish(result);
   }
```

`Interface` example taken from linked answer above and adjusted/commented for clarity. So be sure to upvote that answer if it helps anyone.

Comment: Nice answer.  OP - in general you may want to read about the rules and types of nested classes as per the java standard: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @codeMagic: Thank you for your reply. I want to be able to access the file whose url is stored in `index` after the unzipping operation is completed successfully in `workThread.execute()`. In the question you linked to, I dont understand how the interface `AsyncResponse` was initialized. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: @Sriram I have edited. I hope that clears it up a little. Please give it a try and ask when you get stuck.

Comment: @codeMagic: How do I initialize `delegate`? It is `null` in the snippet above. I also edited the question a little more. I need to access a file from the unzipped folder if the unzipping is a success. However, because the unzip is being implemented by `AsyncTask`, the line after `workThread.execute()` gets executed even before the unzip, resulting in `NullExceptions`. I need to sort of suspend the UI while the unzip operation is taking place. Is `AsyncTask` the best candidate for the job then or should I instead do the Unzip in another activity?

Comment: you can see initializing of delegate from url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a