# Android, async and progress dialogs

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have following piece of code:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    List<MenuItem> menuItems;

    public void importList(View v) {
        menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.context, "TITLE", "MSG");

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(context); // Context is here because I tried to create ProgressDialog inside pre/postExecute, but it doesn't work either
        task.execute();
        try {
            // menuItems = task.get();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // : (
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        this.context = this;
    }
}
```

When I comment the line, where i get values from AsyncTask ("menuItems = task.get()") everythings work ok. But when I uncomment it, ProgressDialog appears AFTER the task is finished, and value returned. Why is that?

I think that it has sth to do with these contexts (that's why I included onCreate method) but I don't have any idea how to fix it. Obviously, I want ProgressDialog to display BEFORE task is finished, not after.

Not sure if relevant - MyAsyncTask is doing http request and some json parsing.

Comment: Agreed with codeMagic. The `AsyncTask` `get()` method is pretty much useless as it blocks the UI thread and effectively makes your asynchronous task a synchronous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that it has sth to do with these contexts

Not at all. Also, when sending `Context` from an `Activity` you don't need to create a variable. Simply use `this` or `ActivityName.this`.

```
 MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
```

> But when I uncomment it, ProgressDialog appears AFTER the task is finished, and value returned. Why is that?

Calling `get()` blocks the `UI`, this is why you don't see the progress until it is done. You don't need to call this. The point of `onProgressUpdate()` is so the background thread (`doInBackground()`) can call it to update the `UI` since `doInBackground()` doesn't run on the `UI`.

Remove that line from your code and never look at it again. If there is a reason that you think you need it then please explain and we can help you find a better way.

**Edit**

[See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) on updating when the task is finished

Comment: Yes, I need that line to obtain the result - menuItems. By this time, I figured it out thanks to this: Android ASync task ProgressDialog isn't showing until background thread finishes (Not sure why I didn't see that topic before)

So how can I pass the result to my Activity? Workflow is like that

User press the button. AsyncTask is started, it fetches content from the server and use it to produce menuItems array - in this time, I want the user see waiting dialog. In Activity, when I have my menuItems, I can finally display AlertDialog with these menuItems.

Comment: See my edit. That answer covers doing it if its an inner class and if not it covers using an `Interface` to send back the results. Even has a short example