# UI gets black on calling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In `onCreate()` I'm showing a `ProgressDialog` and then calling `AsyncTask`  which is non 
`Activity`. In this situation the screen goes black up to 30 seconds. How can I 
resolve  black ui issue?

this from Activity

```
showdialog("Your call is being connected with available agent...Please wait!"); 
response = new GetAvailableLink(ConferenceActivity.this).execute()
                .get();
```

Comment: To get help you will need to post the `AsyncTask` code and how you are calling it. There's a good chance you are calling `.get()` which will block the UI. But can't say anymore without seeing your code.

Comment: will you please help me how can i send you the code to you

Comment: You don't need to send it to me. Use the "edit" button below the tags in your post and copy/paste only **the most relevant** parts into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just as I said in a comment, it is from calling `.get()` on your `AsyncTask` which is a blocking call so your UI won't proceed and it eliminates the point of the task being asynchronous.

You need to remove `.get()`. Show your `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623294/android-async-and-progress-dialogs/18623323#18623323) and a [linked answer in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) should help