# Async Task does not start from non activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my code in the activity in my project:

```
    CustomClass custom = new CustomClass(); 
    //Passing an array list
    result = custom.getResults(list);
```

Here `CustomClass` is a class in the library project and the method `getResults(list)` starts an `AsyncTask`.

`getResults()` method :

```
    public List<String> getResults(List<String> string){        
        List<String> result= new ArrayList<String>();
        BackgroundTask task =  new BackgroundTask();
        task.execute(string);
        result= task.get();
        return result;
    }
```

My Async task :

```
    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Integer, List<String> >{
    List<String> results= new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(List<String>... params) {
        for (int i=0; i<params[0].size();i++) {
            // someOperation
        }
        return results; 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


}
```

Problem : The `AsyncTask` is not started.When I debug and try to enter into the `AsyncTask` class I get `The source attachment does not contain the source for the file classloader.class`. Can someone help me here ? thank you.

Comment: AsyncTask is not designed for such use-case. Go through this link for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @NitinSethi This looks like perfectly valid use to me.

Comment: Do you get any exception//crash?

Comment: No crashes or exception..

Comment: AsyncTask must be created and execute called on the UI thread.  Is the GetResults method called on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes..It is called from my main activity..

Comment: Using `.get()` could be a problem...it will block the `UI`. You should use an [interface instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask). But this wouldn't keep the task from executing. You have put a breakpoint at the first line in `doInBackground()`?

Comment: If you aren't positive that its not getting called and you just aren't getting the result then `get()` may the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get() method blocks the UI thread which means onPreExecute can't run (it has to run in the UI thread)   Thus the background thread will never  be started.

Get rid of the call to get() and move the "return the value" logic to onPostExecute.

And *NEVER* block when you are in the UI thread.

Comment: Background Information.   The UI thread runs an event loop (see Android Looper and Handler for details) This is equivalent to the event loop in Windows/MacOS/etc.

Comment: The event loop only processes one event at a time -- right now it is processing whatever user action called GetResults().  Calling execute() on the async task posts a new event to be processed -- the one that will call onPreExecute.   As soon as this event is complete, then then the next one can be dispatched.

Comment: onPreExecute  starts a thread (or picks one from a thread pool)  This thread also runs a looper.  onPreExecute posts a message to the background thread to actually call doInBackground.

Comment: By not returning from GetResults you are blocking this entire mechanism.