# Start AsyncTask in Method and return its value

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I hope the question is I want to create a method which starts an AsyncTask, waits until the Task ends and then return the value which is provided in the onPostExecute method. So from my main I only want to call the method and get the value which is returned by te AsyncTask. Is that possible? And how does this method have to look like?

Comment: Post what you have so far. Also, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute AsyncTask and do call the particular method which contains logic onPostExecute() method. See the example code what i have used.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

customContactList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ContactsAsyncTask newTask = new ContactsAsyncTask(this);
    newTask.execute();
}

private class ContactsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String> >{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private SecondActivity context;



    public ContactsAsyncTask(SecondActivity secondActivity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = secondActivity;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {            
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        context.useContacts(result);    
    }

public void useContacts(ArrayList<String> data) {

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(SecondActivity.this,data);
    customContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have an instance of AsyncTask called task. In such case you do:

```
task.execute(parameters);
Result result = task.get();
```

Method `get()` will wait until task is completed and will return result from it.

P.S. You are trying to execute asynchronous task synchronously, which raises a question - "Do you need AsyncTask at all"?

Comment: -1 for suggesting `get()` +1 for describing the effects of it like freezing the `UI` until its done. There are a lot of reasons for needing to do what the OP is trying to do and ways to do it efficiently like using an `interface`

Comment: Still need when download Image from the Internet inside a callback method which return this image.