# NullPointerException in getResources

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, getresource

I have activity and class. In activity I do HTTP GET request (HttpClass.java), then in GetMethod.java I do Asynctask. In onPostExecute function I want to return to activity and parse data with JSON. It works, but when I try to create layout with textview and button programmaticaly for every item of data array, it throws NullPointerException.

Code:

**HttpClass.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httplayout);
    cont = this;
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llHttp);
    sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svHttp);
    //httptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    GetMethod test = new GetMethod();
    test.execute(new String[] {"url"}); 
}

public void getResultData(String result) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    resultdata = result;

    JSONObject jObject;
    jObject = new JSONObject(resultdata);

    //JSONObject object = jObject.getJSONObject("pharms");
    JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("pharms");

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString();
    phone = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone").toString();
    latitude = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude").toString();
    longitude = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude").toString();
    address = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("address").toString();

    RelativeLayout ll2 = new RelativeLayout(cont);
    //ll2.setOrientation(Orientation.ho)

    Button call = new Button(cont);
    call.setId(i+1);
    call.setClickable(true);
    call.setTypeface(font);
    call.setText(R.string.call);
    call.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 176, 128));
    call.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)call.getLayoutParams();
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params1.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 0);
    call.setLayoutParams(params1);
    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
    ll2.addView(call);
    TextView tv = new TextView(cont);
    tv.setId(i+1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
    params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params3.setMargins(10, 25, 0, 0);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params3);
    tv.setText(name + "\n" + phone);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setTypeface(font2);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    ll2.addView(tv);

    ll.addView(ll2);
}
}
```

**And this is GetMethod.java class**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
      for (String url : urls) {
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();               
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return data;
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        HttpClass hc = new HttpClass();
        try {
            hc.getResultData(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: LogCat log

```
    09-17 01:35:53.955: W/System.err(18700):          java.lang.NullPointerException 
    09-17 01:35:53.980:    W/System.err(18700):     at    android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:332) 
    09-17    01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):     at    android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3322) 
    09-17 01:35:53.980:    W/System.err(18700):     at    android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:421) 
    09-17 01:35:53.980:    W/System.err(18700):     at    android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:180) 
    09-17    01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):     at    com.example.behealthy.HttpClass.getResultData(HttpClass.java:77)
    09-17 01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):    at    com.example.behealthy.GetMethod.onPostExecute(GetMethod.java:44)
    09-17 01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):    at    com.example.behealthy.GetMethod.onPostExecute(GetMethod.java:1) 
    09-17    01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):     at    android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 
    09-17 01:35:53.980:    W/System.err(18700):     at    android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 
    09-17    01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):     at    android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    09-17 01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):    at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    09-17    01:35:53.980: W/System.err(18700):     at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    09-17 01:35:53.980:    W/System.err(18700):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
    09-17    01:35:53.985: W/System.err(18700):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    09-17    01:35:53.985: W/System.err(18700):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    09-17 01:35:53.985:    W/System.err(18700):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    09-17 01:35:53.985: W/System.err(18700):    at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
    09-17    01:35:53.985: W/System.err(18700):     at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Logcat says that it's NullPointerException in RelativeLayout ll2 = new RelativeLayout(cont);

Comment: That can't be where the `NPE` occurs. It can be the cause of it however, please post the logcat so we can see exactly where it is.

Comment: What is `HttpClass`? Your `Activity` is called `HttpActivity` where your method is.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, activity is called HttpClass. Add logcat log

Comment: I thought that may have been the case, it happens. See the answer I provided. That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating an `Activity` like this is wrong which is why you get the `NPE`

```
  HttpClass hc = new HttpClass();
    try {
        hc.getResultData(result);
```

This is obviously a separate class so what you want to do is create an `interface` to give a callback when the task has finished.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) gives an example of using an `interface` with your `AsyncTask`.

If it were an inner class of your `Activity` then you could just call the function directly from `onPostExecute()` but if you need it to be a separate file then you will want to follow the example in the link.

Comment: It works, thanks. But there is another problem. Function call.onClick isn't called. Can you help me? Or should I start new topic?

Comment: Hmmm...not exactly sure off-hand. You have put a break point in there to make sure it doesn't enter? I'm not sure if you can do it that way or if you need to set the `onClick()` by doing `call.setOnClickListener(this);` then put `onClick()` outside of the method.

Comment: Such a simple decision) Putting onClick() outside is working. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome...glad its working and we both learned something. That's the magic of SO :)