# How to remove background from thread

Tags: android, layout, timer, timertask

I am using Timer to check a condition periodically and want to remove background if found true condition. But it is giving me an error.

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

My code is :

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(!active){
                    fl.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);// this line causing error !

                }


            }}, 500,500);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use run runOnUithread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212631/how-to-use-run-runonuithread)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use at least two methods to do that:

**1. runOnUIThread Activity's method**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

**2. Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to touch views in main thread like that:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

t.schedule(new TimerTask(){

mHandler.post(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(!active){
                fl.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);// this line causing error !

            }
        }
        });
        }, 500,500);
```