# Progress dialog android json

Tags: android, json, progressdialog

I have a problem wih my progressdialog, my app searches for the data from json and after that the dialog comes, but I want it at this time while he collects the data. where is my mistake?

There is the edited code
logcat( FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException)
JSON ([{"name":"Test"}])
edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new TheTask().execute();
}
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        JSONObject jObject = result;
        try {
            String aJsonString = jObject.getString("name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (List<String>) result));
        // parse and set List adapter here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
                "dialog message", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("***");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(50);`

You are calling sleep on the ui thread which blocks it. Remove it.

Use `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Show progress dialog in `onPreExecute`. Do your http request in `doInbackground`. Dismiss dialog in `onPostExecute` and update ui accordingly.

To invoke

```
 new TheTask().execute();
```

Then

```
 class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progress.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
                            "dialog message", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // http request
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new TheTask().execute();
    }
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        // parse and set List adapter here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
                "dialog message", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("******");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
}
```

Edit2:

```
   class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
        for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++)
        {

            JSONObject jb = result.getJSONObject(i) ;
            String name = jb.getString("name");
            list.add(name);
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
                "dialog message", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("******");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: make asynctask an inner class of activity class also pot your updated code

Comment: how can i do this? im new in this android programming

Comment: this should be difficult if you know java. post your cod

Comment: @user3241084 see the edit and you need to parse the json

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MEvZVMZE there I want to parse the Json but then my app quits

Comment: @user3241084 you need to post you code here. I am not going to open a link and look at your code and you need to post the stacktrace as well to indicate the crash

Comment: @user3241084 edit your post and add the code. Code should ne added in comments and post the logcat also result is a JSONObject not a list or string array what you are doing makes no sense

Comment: @user3241084 that is not json object its a josn array

Comment: @user3241084 check edit2 it will work. if oyu have posted the json right

Comment: is there also a way to safe the json data at the phone that you can see the data also if your phone is offline?

Comment: @user3241084 yes its called caching. do ask a new question and do accept this answer by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460461/json-data-available-offline there its going on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You call `Thread.sleep(50)` on the `UI Thread` so the `UI` freezes until its done. Move your operations to an `AsyncTask` and `sleep()` in `doInBackground()`. Put all of your network code in `doInBackground()` also.

You can use `AsyncTasks` other methods to update the `UI`.

[See this answer for an example of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105) if you are unfamiliar

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)