# Android : Show loading image while check & download xml file

Tags: android, xml, loading

This is my code to check Internet and download XMl and show in a `ListView` 
What I want is, while XML loads , show my custom `layout` or show a loading picture .
If I should Use `AsynceTask` please explain how . Thanks.

```
       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_COST,KEY_NAME,KEY_DESC,KEY_ID},     new int

[] {
                                R.id.cost,R.id.name,R.id.desciption,R.id.linke});


        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an `AsyncTask` would be good for this.

1. Show whatever image/layout you want while loading in `onPreExecute()`. You can use a `ProgressDialog`/`ProgressBar` if you want or show something else here.
2. Do your parsing in `doInBackground()`
3. Then dismiss your `ProgressDialog`/`ProgressBar`, image, or whatever you decide to use in `onPostExecute()`. Also, update your `Adapter` in this method.
4. You can make the `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `Activity` if you don't need it anywhere else to make it easier.

Be sure you read through the [AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) a couple times to understand how they work.

[Here is an example of setting up an AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

 progress = ProgressDialog.show(activity, activity.getString(R.string.spinner_title), activity.getString(R.string.spinner_message_retrieving), true);}

 @Override
    protected void doInBackground() {
        super.onPreExecute();
// do here network stuff
}
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {      
progress.dismiss();}
```

this is a part of your asynktask methode