# Warning "Application is not responding" during FTP Upload

Tags: android, ftp

I programmed my first app today with this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

In addition I added an FTP Upload for a File from SD Card to my own FTP, which is working also well. With on exception. I'm getting the (translated) error "Application is not responding, WAIT or CLOSE" (https://imgur.com/C2pLaiO) because the file which I am uploading is about 30MB so that it needs some time.

For the ftp Upload I used the library ftp4j-1.7.2.jar from sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

What do I need to do to get rid of this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing this file transfer on the `UI Thread` and since it takes some time, it is causing your application to hault until it is finished. You can put that code in an `AsyncTask`. This will help in a couple ways

1. It can do the file transfer on a background `Thread` while allowing not holding up your `UI` and giving you this ugly message
2. `AsyncTask` has built-in methods which allow you to do operations on the ui such as showing a `ProgressDialog`/`ProgressBar`

You would put your "heavy-lifting" code in `doInBackground()` and your ui stuff (showing/dismissing progress) in `onPreExecute()`/`onPostExecute()` and you can do things such as update a `ProgressBar` by calling `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()` which will call `onProgressUpdate()`.

[See this answer for an example of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to upload the file, as it doesnt stop the UI from running while the upload occurs (hence, no "Application is not responding" will be shown).