# How to update a View before heavy freezing method?

Tags: android, view, screen, lag

I use a code that access HTTP service to receive login data, and before it, I tried to show a processing dialog, but it did not showed up. Then I tried to simply change the button label to tell the user to wait until data returns, but it also did not work. That's my code:

```
        tryingToLoginDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Por Favor Aguarde", "Efetuando Login...", true);
        btn_Entrar.setText("Wait while logins...");
        btn_Entrar.invalidate();
        App.webService.Login(txtLogin.getText().toString(), txtSenha.getText().toString());
        String LoginUserData = App.webService.getUserData(); /* this method freezes the app but do not crash it cause ThreadPolicy permit all*/
        /* here some if's */
        tryingToLoginDialog.dismiss();
        btn_Entrar.setText("Login");
        btn_Entrar.invalidate();
```

Comment: You say you tried two different things but I can't tell if you've read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html. Please focus on one attempt & provide code & logcat.

Comment: Have you thought about using an `AsyncTask`? Changing the thread policy is not recommended.

Comment: [Here is an example of setting it up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Answer (score 0):

You should use AsynTask. This has 4 different method `doInBackground()` This method run in background(not in UI Thread) In your case you can do your networking stuff here and other three methods are `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` run in UI Thread So you can use these function to update GUI.

You were saying you want to show dialog so setup  progressdialog in `onPreExecute()` and do your freezing stuff in `doInBackground()` and use other method according to your need.

See detail [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Not exactly a detailed guide you've got here under the term "detail", I'll rather leave this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working?lq=1

Comment: I think the link i mention contains enough explanation to understand AsynTask. I don't know why you discouraged that. You should review you vote, i think.