# Android:Is my Async Method working?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I decided that in order to speed up my application and avoid crashing i would run my method PetrolPriceString on a background thread through the AsyncTask method. However even though my application does still run there is no speed up and looking at my code i'm convinced i have made an error in my placement of the method as well as i think maybe some of my code may be wrong despite no errors. My method simply runs the method PetrolPriceString in a background thread and returns the urlString which i'm hoping will contain a URL to an RSS feed specified.

```
    package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetrolPriceActivity extends Menu 
{
    private TextView response;
    private TextView errorText;
    private String result;
    private String petrolPriceURL;
    private static final String TAG = "PetrolPrice";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
        petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");
        }
        // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
        response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
        response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        try
        {
            // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
            result =  petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL);

            // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the RSS stream
            // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
            // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
            // This will need to be removed at some point
            response.setText(result);
        }
        catch(IOException ae)
        {
            // Handle error
            response.setText("Error");
            // Add error info to log for diagnostics
            errorText.setText(ae.toString());
        } 

    }

    // End of onCreate

    // Method to handle the reading of the data from the RSS stream
    private static String petrolPriceString(String urlString)throws IOException
    {
        String result = "";
        InputStream anInStream = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // Check that the connection can be opened
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try
        {
            // Open connection
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            // Check that connection is Ok
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                String line = new String();
                while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                {
                    result = result + "\n" + line;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }

        // Return result as a string for further processing
         new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            IOException exception = null;
            @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + "hello");
                    return petrolPriceString(params[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    exception = e;
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (exception != null) {
                    // handle our exception

                } else {
                    // handle our result
                }
            }
        }.execute(urlString);

        return result;

    }
    // End of petrolPriceString
 // End of Activity class
}
```

I'm rather new to android and very new to the concept of threads so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: well the first code yes does work as for the actual asynctask code well im not too sure on that one. I have no errors if thats what u mean

Comment: `AsyncTask` actually don't speed up execution, it just separates it from UI Thread which means that UI Thread can perform other job at the time.

Comment: so i should move all my code in PetrolPriceString to the AsyncTask? Yeh Sasha Salauyou i want the method to run in the background as it can cause errors if i add more later on

Comment: (String urlString)throws IOException - how would i do this in my inner class?

Comment: ive edited the code is this better? thank you everyone for helping me understand this as well as hopefully have the right code now

Comment: @user3071845 I've rolled back your edit. Please don't change the original code as it will be unhelpful for future users with the same problem. If you have a new question then post it separately

Comment: right so how will i show the eventual solution? also was my edit the correct code? will i create a separate code segment after my original code stating its the solution?

Comment: You don't need to post a complete solution with your code because other people are surely going to have different code. You *could* add the solution as an answer but it typically isn't needed. There are multiple ways to accomplish it but the solution **is** to move all of that code to a background thread and run it only once.

Comment: i added an answer simply to help others. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are only running

```
Log.v(TAG, "index=" + "hello");
return petrolPriceString(params[0]);
```

on a background thread. When you first call this method here

```
result =  petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL)
```

it is running through that network code then running the `AsyncTask` which calls the method again. It seems like it is calling itself recursively.

I would suggest making the `AsynctTask` it's own inner class then execute it, running all of the code in your method.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105) on how to do that.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: how do i execute it within my PetrolPriceActivity activity? would i simply use TalkToServer AsyncTask = new MyTask();
AsyncTask.execute();

Comment: @user3071845 use the example in the link to create an inner class in your `Activity` (you can name it whatever you want). Then execute it that way wherever you need to. `AsyncTask.execute(petrolPriceURL)` but that variable should be camel-case to adhere to Java standards.

Comment: hi i think ive got it working however how would i pass my result variable from my inner class to my petrolPriceActivity class? this is all i need to get it working as when i check my logcat i do have the correct information

Comment: As that linked answer shows, since it's an inner class of the `Activity`, you can simply update your `View` in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

*I wrote an answer myself to help others with the same problem.*

Put the `petrolPriceString(..)` code into an inner class of `PetrolPriceActivity`, which extends `AsyncTask`.

And execute it in the onCreate method:

```
new asyncTask().execute(petrolPriceURL);
```

Anything done afterwards to update the UI is handled on onPostExecute rather than onCreate.

```
package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetrolPriceActivity extends Menu {
    private TextView response;
    private TextView errorText;
    private String petrolPriceURL;
    private static final String TAG = "PetrolPrice";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!=null) {
            petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");
        }
        // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
        new asyncTask().execute(petrolPriceURL);
    }

    public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String...parmans) {
               String urlString = petrolPriceURL;
               {
                    String result = "";
                    InputStream anInStream = null;
                    int response = -1;
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(urlString);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    try {
                        conn = url.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    // Check that the connection can be opened
                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    try {
                        // Open connection
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();
                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                        // Check that connection is OK
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                            anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                            BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                            // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                            String line = new String();
                            while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null) {
                                result = result + "\n" + line;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                            try {
                                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                    return result;
                }
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
               response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
               response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

               try {
                    // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
                    result =  doInBackground(petrolPriceURL);

                    response.setText(result);
                    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);
                } catch(Exception ae) {
                    // Handle error
                    response.setText("Error");
                    // Add error info to log for diagnostics
                    errorText.setText(ae.toString());
                }
            }
        }
}
```