# Sharing Functions Between Classes

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm building a small test app that interacts with some basic php scripts on my server.

Essentially I have three activities that each download the same information which I parse in slightly different way for each.

At the moment I have simply copied the async task function to each of the activities.

I'm sure this is a needless replication and that their must be a way to share this function between each of the activities.

Is it possible for me to hold the async task in a separate class and call it from each?

Eg. I can call "async task class" from Activity A,B or C, it starts on a background thread then returns the unparsed results to the ui thread when its done?

Comment: Thanks for this codeMagic, but I still cant work out how I am supposed to 1) Notify the main thread that the operation is complete and 2) retrieve the result from the download on the main thread?

Comment: That answer shows you how to implement an `interface` into any `Activity` which calls the `AsyncTask` that is in it's own file. Give it a try. You just implement the callback method in your activity and send the response through `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Ah got you, thanks, hadn't read far enough down. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Go through that and if you can't get it working then you can post a new question with detailed information on where you are stuck. It sounds like you have a basic understanding of `AsyncTasks` but if not [this answer might help also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Comment: Yeh, the first one you posted got me there perfectly. Shouldn't have replied without reading till the end. Apologies. Thanks again.