# Android ASyncTask wrong result

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Im trying to do a GET request to a server and return the response. Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = getBaseUrl() + params[0] + "?" + params[1] + "=" + params[2];
    String response = "";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String getURL = url;
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
        if (resEntityGet != null) {
            // do something with the response
            response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            return response;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

When debugging response has the right value but when I call the method the response becomes something else. I call it like this:

```
 HTTPConnector connector = new HTTPConnector("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/");
    try {
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> result = connector.execute("GetSeries.php", "seriesname", "Arrow");
        String result2 = result.toString();
        System.out.println(result2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result here is something else than the response in the doInBackground method. How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105) on using `AsyncTask`. You can't get the result until the task has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As see doc [AsyncTask.execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  *task returns itself (this) so that the caller can keep a reference to it* which we will use to check the status of `AsyncTask` like is task is running,pending or finished instead of return result of `doInBackground`.

`onPostExecute` method is called when `doInBackground`  method execution done to deliver result to UI Thread:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // update UI here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use AsyncTask in a wrong way. You should get the response String in its onPostExecute() method, code like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // The result is the response String you want.
    }
```

Comment: To the person who vote down my answer: I really want to know what's wrong with it.