# Set text after complete thread

Tags: android

I have a problem. Why a data in setText method are set incorrecetly?

MainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_city_name);
        textViewTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_current_temperature);

        new Thread(new WeatherYahoo()).start();

        Weather weather = new Weather();

        textViewCity.setText(weather.getCity());
        textViewTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(weather.getTemperature()));
    }
```

Data were downloaded and set correctly in Weather class (I use JSON) but on the screen showed empty string form textViewCity and 0 for textViewTemperature.

Comment: can you show the Weather, constructor?

Comment: It doesn't  looks like you are setting any properties of the weather object before you access them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105?s=2|4.1738#18898105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in your activity executes on the UI thread. So this is happening because you are trying to set the text right after you started a new `Thread` with `WeatherYahoo`, so you don't wait for the result, but just output empty value. I would recommend you to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for such kind of calls and retrieving results on UI thread. So you can do all your work you do in `WeatherYahoo` class in `doInBackground()` method instead and output the result in `onPostExecute()` method. As an example:

```
 private class WeatherYahooTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Weather> {
     protected Weather doInBackground(Void... params) {
         // do any kind of work you need (but NOT on the UI thread)
         // ...
         return weather;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
        // do any kind of work you need to do on UI thread
        textViewCity.setText(weather.getCity());
        textViewTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(weather.getTemperature()));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I try this, but how to use findViewById, setText etc in WeatherYahoo when I have main screen in MainActivity class and I want there set text.

Comment: You don't need to use "findViewById, setText etc in WeatherYahoo". See the example I've added

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Wait for the thread to finish downloading the json using:

  ```
  Thread t = new Thread(new WeatherYahoo()).start();
  t.join();
  Weather weather = new Weather();
  ```
- Or you can use asynctasks like Yuriy posted.