# App Crashing using Android Studio, Sunshine App, cant get the concept of AsynTask

Tags: android

I m particularly new in programming, and not getting to figure out the error, whenever i run it, either on emulator or on mobile, its says, App has stopped working.
please help me figure it out
thanx in advance

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
         .commit();

         }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**ForecastFragement**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nabahat on 7/8/2015.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;

            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.sunshine.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingRight="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

here is log

```
02-04 07:12:41.022  11478-11478/? E/libEGL﹕ call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-04 07:17:25.447  12449-12449/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:27.697  12474-12474/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:28.202  12492-12492/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:28.313  12506-12506/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:28.457  12524-12524/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:28.706  12547-12547/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:28.802  12547-12553/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-04 07:17:28.853  12547-12547/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4727)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:41)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 07:17:29.027  12563-12563/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:29.361  12580-12580/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:29.550  12599-12599/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:29.609  12612-12612/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:32.472  12639-12639/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:34.982      493-511/? E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ Object tried to add another callback
    java.lang.Exception: Called by
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardUpdateMonitor.registerCallback(KeyguardUpdateMonitor.java:1108)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardSelectorView.onResume(KeyguardSelectorView.java:331)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardHostView.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardHostView.java:1118)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardViewManager.java:403)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleNotifyScreenOn(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1813)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.access$2400(KeyguardViewMediator.java:106)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator$4.handleMessage(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-04 07:17:35.083     120-1870/? E/AudioMTKHardware﹕ setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=on"
02-04 07:17:41.110  12672-12672/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 07:17:41.247  12672-12672/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4727)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:41)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 07:17:41.285      493-513/? E/AppErrorDialog﹕ Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
02-04 07:17:45.682      120-438/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
02-04 07:17:45.682      120-438/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
02-04 07:17:50.354      645-645/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ Sorted scan results
02-04 07:17:50.354      645-645/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ f4:3e:61:92:4b:21 freq=2462 qual=0 noise=0 level=-83 flags=0xb
02-04 07:17:50.354      645-645/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ IEs
02-04 07:17:50.354      645-645/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕
```

Comment: You need to post the logcat but [Here is an answer I gave on using AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Comment: You aren't actually using your async task, so the problem isn't there.  Look in your stack trace.

Comment: added the log, as well as, i was basicaly following the tutorial, and at this stage, the could had to run on device,  showing the data which was stored in array, this aint happening here

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in your main activity_main.xml you have used a fragment tag which loads the required fragment, **BUT you have used the wrong name of the fragment**.
you have used     `android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"`                           you should use `android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment`

since you are doing it in xml remove the transaction code written inside onCreate().

It has nothing to do with async task

Comment: what does it mean by transaction code inside on create()?

Comment: As well as, no affect after correcting the name in main.xml :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm also taking the same course. Commenting out the below lines did the trick for me -

```html
if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
         .commit();

         }
```

But this is not the right solution. The app works by doing this but these lines exist in the course code. Maybe you could get a hint of what is going wrong with the code above!