# How does android Asynctask work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am currently doing a project on creating a dynamic table on actvity containing values. This values are retrieved from Link through Json. I have Onclick Listner enabled on each row of table. And this activity work like this->

***First activity*** (Tablerow clicked) <--(Intent/back)-->**Second Activity**(Another table View)

There is a problem that sometimes my screen freezes. And I am a bit new to android and is just into the basics. I have heard about Asynctask, but i don't know how to implement it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this answer Asycntask usage already discussed here.
[Using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask)

or got to android official documentation for understanding asynctask clearly
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html