# Android:SimpleAdapter error

Tags: android, simpleadapter

Hello i have this SimpleAdapter in order to display some notifications in a ListView.These notifications are in `ArrayList` localist. here is the code:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,localist, R.layout.rss_list_item,new String[] {"title","pubDate"},new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.pubDate });
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The thing is that it shows me three errors here.The first one is at localist and says"localist cannot be resolved to a variable".

The second and the third one are at

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

one at the dot that says "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" and the other at the adapter inside the parenthesis that says "Syntax error on token "adapter", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token". I thing the second and the third error are caused because of the first error. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?Thans a lot in advance!

EDIT:
     the localist is declared and created in other activity
here is the code:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> localist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String xml = ParseXMLmethods.getXML();
        Document doc = ParseXMLmethods.XMLfromString(xml);
        if (doc != null) {
        NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        ZERO_FLAG = false;
        if (children.getLength() == 0) {
        ZERO_FLAG = true;
        publishProgress();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) children.item(i);
        map.put("title", ParseXMLmethods.getValue(e, "title"));
        map.put("pubDate", ParseXMLmethods.getValue(e, "pubDate"));
        map.put("link", ParseXMLmethods.getValue(e, "link"));
        map.put("description",ParseXMLmethods.getValue(e, "description"));
        localist.add(map);

        }
```

Comment: Show us some more code. Where do you define and create the localist?

Comment: @SimonSays here you go

Comment: Is this the only place that you try to use `localist`?

Comment: @codeMagic yes thats the only place

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? Those seem like strange errors from what I am seeing. And where do you have your `ListView` and `Adapter` code that you posted at the top?

Comment: @codeMagic that didn't work...can i ask you a question ? do i have to somehow pass `localist` to the activity that uses the `SimpleAdapter`?

Comment: Yes, definitely if the `AsyncTask` isn't an inner class of that class

Comment: @codeMagic can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: See my answer. To make it an inner class just put the `AsyncTask` inside of the other class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, I think I see what's going on. It looks like your `Asynctask` is in a separate file than your `Adapter`. There are several ways to fix this. One would be to use an `interface` to set the variable in your `Adapter` once your task has finished.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) for creating an `interface` for an `AsyncTask`.

A simpler way would be to make your `AsyncTask` an inner class of where your `Adapter` is and make `localist` a member variable of that class so that both have access to it. Then you could set your `Adapter` and your `ListView` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: still doesn't work:/ Can i send you my code to see if i have done it correctly?

Comment: Did you make `localist` a member variable (declare it outside of a method)?