# Android http request on main thread error

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using Kevin Sawicki's library for HTTP requests in my Android application. The actual call to the library methods for making the request is made in a class file (it's not called from an activity) called `TemplateHelper`. The method that calls the HttpRequest library in my TemplateHelper class looks like this

```
public static JSONObject GetTemplates() {
    try {
        return new JSONObject(HttpRequest.get("http://myapi.mycompany.com/templates").body());
    } catch (HttpRequestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

From my activity i then call `TemplateHelper.GetTemplates()` to get the data. However, when i do this Android throws the exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
A quick Google search shows me the code for running the HTTPRequest on a separate thread. But if i run the code in a separate thread, how can i return the result to the main thread?

Comment: Don't. Use asynchronous flow.

Comment: If you will use `AsyncTask`, `onPostExecute()` method will be run on the main thread after task finished.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) will show you how to implement an `interface` with `AsyncTask` so you can get a `callBack` to the `MainActivity` when your task has finished.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make network requests on the main thread. You'll get the error you are seeing now. You need to use either `AsyncTask` or you need to create a new thread. Personally, I'd use `AsyncTask`. When you use `AsyncTask` you can use the `onPostExecute` method to return the value to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Async Task in yout TemplateHelper class, Async task runs in a different thread so main thread exception will not be there

Check this [tutorial](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/), this is exactly you need to do.