# No enclosing instance in scope - method call between classes

Tags: java, android, class, methods

i'm pretty new in programming android Apps actually this is my first, so sorry for my (maybe simple) question.

All i want to do is to post some values by httprequest on a website (this works fine so far) and get a message back, if it was success full (there's the problem). So my class MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button sendButton;
private Button graficButton;

[...]
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

[...]
new ExecutePost().execute(zusammen);
return;

}


public void checkResponse(Integer responseCode) {
    if(responseCode == 200){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(R.string.response_ok)
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.error_ok, null)
            .show();
        return;
    }else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage(R.string.response_false)
        .setNeutralButton(R.string.error_ok, null)
        .show();
    return;
    }

}
```

In class ExecutePost I try to call the function checkResponse from the MainActivity class but there i get the Compiler Error:

> No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope

This is how i coded the class ExecutePost:

```
public class ExecutePost  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse>{

private IOException exception;
private ClientProtocolException clientException;

@Override
public HttpResponse doInBackground(String... alles) {

    works fine
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse resRes) {
    Integer code = resRes.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    super.onPostExecute(resRes);
    MainActivity.this.checkResponse(code);
}
```

}

I get the error message in the last line for **MainActivity.this.**checkResponse(code); I guess it has something to do with instances / static non-statics methods and so one...

Thanks in advance.
Timo

Comment: if you want to pass the code to the activity class use a interface

Comment: [See this answer on using an interface with AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)

Comment: or make asynctask an inner class of MainActivity

Comment: Whats the need to call back Main Activity in post execute.You can show alert dialog in postExecute based on the result..

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working fine with the interface!