# How to handle UI in asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Generally I  update UI in postExecute method.
e.g.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity{
TextView textSample;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.aadd_addtocheck);
        textSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lin);
                STask sampleTask = new Stask();
                sampleTask.execute();
}
class GetAdd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {


        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
            return u.getNewAdd();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                    textSample.setText(result.getString("Something");
}
```

However, my asyncTask become large and I want to move them to different class (before they were a subclass). Therefor, I wonder how to to update UI ( like setting texviews) when asynctask will be a separete class.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) about using an `interface` with `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to put the AsyncTask in a separate file, you might be likely to reuse that `AsyncTask` from other Activities, so I think that the best practise would be to make a callback to the activity so it does all the UI handling.

For doing that what you should do is create an Interface like the following:

```java
public interface OnGetAddCompletedListener {
    public void onGetAddCompleted(String text);
}
```

Receive the callback in the constructor of your `AsyncTask` and call the method in it in `onPostExecute`

```java
public class GetAdd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    private OnGetAddCompletedListener callback;

    public GetAdd(OnGetAddCompletedListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
        return u.getNewAdd();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onGetAddCompleted(result.getString("Something");
    }
}
```

And then, implement the interface in the `Activity` you are executing it so it handles the UI modifications when you get the data in the `AsycTask`:

```java
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnGetAddCompletedListener {
    TextView textSample;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.aadd_addtocheck);
        textSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lin);
                STask sampleTask = new Stask();
                sampleTask.execute();
    }

    public void onGetAddCompleted(String text) {
        textSample.setText(text);
    }
}
```

With this approach, if you decide to reuse that AsyncTask from other activity you will be able to do different things when the `AsyncTask` has ended in case you want to do so.

Comment: I am a bit confused about one thing - if i have 2 running activity which implements OnGetAddCompletedListener; one of them starts asyncTask. When async task will be finished callback will be recieved by both activity or only by activity which started asynctask?

Comment: With this approach what you are doing is putting a _refference_ to the calling Activity (or wherever you are executing the `AsyncTask` from so when the `onPostExecute` will call the method `onGetAddCompleted` implemented in the Activity you are calling it from. So, if you have ActivityA and ActivityB both implementing `OnGetAddCompletedListener`, when you execute the `AsyncTask` from ActivityA, the `onPostExecute` will call the method implemented in ActivityA and when you execute it from ActivityB `onPostExecute` will call the method implemented in AcitivityB

Answer (score 2):

You pass either the `Context`, `Activity`, or the individual `View`s to the `AsyncTask`'s constructor and store them as member variables, then update them on `onPostExecute()`.

Be sure to store `Context` or `Activity` as a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments into the constructor of your AsyncTask when you call it. Let's say that in your main activity you have the following:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
Stask sampleTask = new Stask(tv);
sampleTask.execute();
```

When you are creating your AsyncTask, you have:

```
class Stask extends AsyncTask ...(){
    final TextView textView; 

    public Stask(Textview inputFromOtherClass){
        this.textView = inputFromOtherClass;
    }
}
```

This way, the TextView created in your main activity can exist as an instance in your AsyncTask.

EDIT:As someone else posted, you can do something similar for the Context, which is useful in creating various instances.