# Android AsyncTask reference

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm implementing a simple download manager.
The main activity is like this:

[image]

For every download button pressed I run a service who have an asynctask for download files and update a progress bar in the notification bar. This is the code of the asynctask:

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    NotificationManager manager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    String title="";
    int counter = 0;
    String url="";
    String videoId="";
    int totalSize=0;

    public DownloadFileFromURL(String title,String videoId){

        this.title = title;
        this.videoId = videoId;
    }

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showNotification();
        ItemDownloaded itemDownloaded = new ItemDownloaded(title+".mp3", videoId, String.valueOf(totalSize));
        id = db.addDownloadedItem(itemDownloaded);


    }

    private void showNotification(){

        manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        /*build the notification*/
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentText("Download in progress")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

        manager.notify(title.hashCode() , notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        this.url = f_url[0];
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            totalSize = lenghtOfFile;

            db.updateTotalSize((int)id, String.valueOf(totalSize));


            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/download/provefile/"+title+".mp3");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                //actualSize = total;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                if((counter == 0) || (counter >21)){
                    publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    if(counter == 0)
                        counter++;
                    else
                        counter = 0;
                }else
                    counter++;

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return "ko";
        }

        return "ok";
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        //progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        //totalLength.setText("/"+humanReadableByteCount(totalSize, true));
        //actualLength.setText(humanReadableByteCount(actualSize, true));

        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        //new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt()
        manager.notify(title.hashCode() , notification);
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded

        notificationBuilder.setProgress(0,0,false);


        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        //new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt()
        manager.notify(title.hashCode() , notification);

        if(result.compareTo("ok")==0)
            downloadSuccesfullComplete(title);
        else
            downloadError(title,url);

        stopSelf();

        /*notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
        .setProgress(0,0,false);


        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        //new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt()
        manager.notify(title.hashCode() , notification);*/
    }

}
```

And this is the notification bar:
[image]

Now I want to show , when users press the show button, in another activity inside a ListView all the files in download (so all the running asynctask) and show a progress for every file with the download progress, like this:
[image]

How I can do??
I try with a database: in progressUpdate of asynctask I update a column of the table with the actual progress and then in ListView adapter I create an asynctask who execute every second a select sql instruction and update the progress  of the progress bar.
But I think this isn't a good solution.
What do you think??

There is a way to save a reference af all the running asynctask and then in an activity get its and get the progressUpdate?? I thinked to use a subclass of android.Application like a singleton and save in it all the reference to the running asynctask.

Hope I explain all right??
Thank you so much

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but if I do then [see this answer about using an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask). This uses a callback in `onPostExecute()` but you should be able to use it in `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface to send the status to the listview. You can use an algorithm like this:

1. - create an interface in the asynctask class, lets say it has an method called **update** with the argument you want to send.
2. - implement it in the listview class.
3. - create a constructor in the asynctask class with argument the interface. 
     For example `asyncTaskClassConstructor(myInterface reference)`
4. - Then when you going to create an instance of the asynctask class you give the reference to the constructor like this: `new asyncTaskClassConstructor(this) etc..`
5. - And then in the `onProgressUpdate` method of asynctask there you should call the interface method we declared **update()** and pass the argument there.
6. - And then in your listview class you use it as you want, for example updating the listview with **notifyDataSetChanged()**

**Edited answer -1**

If you want to know the progress of `Asynctask` you declare an interface with arguments (int progress), and when you want to notify the progress just call `publishProgress()` method of `Asynctask` and inside of that method you call the interface method and the classes that implement that interface  will be notified.

**Edited answer -2**

If you want to update the progress of the file, an efective way of doing it (as i said before) is using an interface, and then you implement that interface in the listview class and update the bar there with  the value (argument values let's say you put a `int value` as method ). And everytime you want to publish the progress to others just call the interface in the `onPublishProgress()` method with the arguments you want to pass.

**Example**

In your asyncTask class you create an interface let's say `asyncTaskEvents` with a method `progress(int value)` and then make an instance variable with the interface:

```
 private asyncTaskEvents events;

 public interface asyncTaskEvents { 
   public void progress(int value);
 }
```

Make an instance variable with the interface, and then add an argument to your constructor to put a reference to the class that is waiting for the progress:

```
public DownloadFileFromURL(String title,String videoId,asyncTaskEvents event){
    this.title = title;
    this.videoId = videoId;
    this.events = event.
}
```

Then in your `onProgressUpdate` method from AsyncTask, you can call the interface to pass
the current progress to the classes that implement it ( in this case the listview class):

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    //Etc...
    events.progress(progress);
}
```

Then implement it in your listviewclass, And in the method implemented `progress(int value)` there you update the progress to the progressBar for example:

```
public void progress(int value){
  //update progress, show message or whatever you want to do here :-)
}
```

You can change the arguments as you want. :)

Comment: Ok it is so good but I want the listview must have number of items as number of running asynctask. How can I know the number of running asynctasks?

Comment: You can't run the same asynctask instance multiple times, just one time. If you want to download multiple downloads and add more download later, i think the best idea would be to use a service because with a service running you download the files and if later you want to download more files you just call the service running and then download the new files.

Comment: Yes I can run multiple asynctask, I use executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR). I yet use a service, infact, my asynctask is inside a service. My problem is how I can know the progress of my multiple asynctask in another activity.

Comment: Ok but what I dont understand is: if the activity with the listview is not running and the asynctask progressUpdate notify the progress to it what  happen??

Comment: You can show a Toast dialog, saying that 1 file has been downloaded.And when the user open the downloader manager then refresh the list with notifyDataSetChanges();

Comment: I have editet my question because I think I not explain my problem good. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if you want an example of what i'm saying.

Comment: Yes please give me an example. Thank you