# AsyncTask, Send data object to Thread UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have my Thread UI. I need to download informations to update interface.
In my AsyncTask, I put data in a class "Program" that i recover in Json and want to send this class to my Thread UI. But i don't Know really how to do that.

My AsyncTask is in outside of my main activity.

**AsyncTask :**

```
    public class GetMediaInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 
    private static final String LOG_TAG = Api.class.getSimpleName();
    private Exception mException = null;

static String url_youtube_unik;
static Gson gson = null;
static String infoProgramDean = null, infoProgramTmdb = null, infoCanal = null, trailerYoutube = null, infoProgramBouygues = null;
String code;
String url;

Program program;
Canal canal;
private Handler handler;

public GetMediaInfo(Handler handler, Program program, Canal canal) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.canal = canal;
    this.program = program;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute () {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG ,"PreExecute GetMediaInfo");
}

protected void onPostExecute (String result) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG ,"PostExecute GetMediaInfo");
    //Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
    //Bundle b = new Bundle();

    if (result != null) {
        //b.putString("functionName", "UpdateInfoScreen");
        //b.putString("message", "Update Info Program");

        // HOW TO SEND MY Program to Thread Ui and update Interface ????????


    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error getCurrentProgram : " + mException.getMessage());
        //b.putString("functionName", "Message");
        //b.putString("message", "Error getCurrentProgram : " + mException.getMessage());
    }   
   // msgObj.setData(b);

   // handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG ,"doInBackground GetMediaInfo");

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Channel qu'on a récupéré
    //String tvChannelId = canal.getId();         <=================================================== A DELETE avec STB
    String tvChannelId = "1";
    boolean found = false;

     gson = new Gson();
     String idProgram = null;
     String nameProgram = null;
     String typeProgram = null;


    // --> Récupération Information du programme en cours + la liste du programme de la chaîne <--
    // Prépare url bouygues Canal
     url = "http://openbbox.flex.bouyguesbox.fr:81/V0/Media/EPG/Live?period=1&TVChannelsId=" + tvChannelId;

     //On récupère information du program avec le site de Bouygues
     try {
        infoCanal = Api.getInfoMedia(url);
        JSONObject myJson; 
        myJson = new JSONObject(infoCanal);

        // "{\"id\": 51,\"nom\": \"Ma Chaîne Sport\", \"ListeProgrammes\": { \"Programme\": [{\"id\": 95347742,\"nom\": \"Bien-être\",\"description\": \"Emission du bien-être.\",\"debut\": \"2014-01-23T06:00:00Z\",\"fin\": \"2014-01-23T06:30:00Z\"}]}}";
        idProgram = myJson.getJSONObject("ListeProgrammes").getJSONArray("Programme").getJSONObject(0).optString("id");
        nameProgram = myJson.getJSONObject("ListeProgrammes").getJSONArray("Programme").getJSONObject(0).optString("nom");

        Log.v("idProgram","= " + idProgram);
        Log.v("nameProgram","= " + nameProgram);
     } catch (ServerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

    //FAKE ID Pour le TEST ID 
    idProgram = "95262486";

    // Prépare url bouygues Info Program
    url = "http://openbbox.flex.bouyguesbox.fr:81/V0/Media/EPG/Live?programId="+ idProgram;

    try {
        JSONObject myJson;
        infoProgramBouygues = Api.getInfoMedia(url);
        myJson = new JSONObject(infoProgramBouygues);
        typeProgram = myJson.getJSONObject("Programme").getJSONObject("ListeGenres").optString("genre");
                Log.v("genreProgram","= " + typeProgram);


        // On ajoute heure de début et fin (format: "debut": "2014-01-22T20:45:00Z)
        String beginningTime = myJson.getJSONObject("Programme").getJSONObject("Diffusion").optString("debut").substring(10);
        String endTime = myJson.getJSONObject("Programme").getJSONObject("Diffusion").optString("fin").substring(10);

        program.setBeginningTime(beginningTime);
        program.setEndTime(endTime);            
    } catch (ServerException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // GENRE == FILM
    if (typeProgram.equals("Film")) {
        // Remplace espaces par des +, puis &apos; par des
        nameProgram = nameProgram.replaceAll("\\s","+").replaceAll("&apos;", "'").replaceAll("&amp;", "");

        //nameProgram = "intouchables"; <============================================================================ A DELETE bon program

        Log.v("nameProgram", "= " + nameProgram);

        // Prépare URL DEAN
        url = "http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q="+nameProgram;

        try {
            infoProgramDean = Api.getInfoMedia(url);
            JSONObject myJson;
            myJson = new JSONObject(infoProgramDean);
            code = null;
            code = myJson.optString("code");                            

            // Film trouvé
            if(code.equals("")) {
                String IdProgramIMDB = myJson.optString("imdbid");
                Log.v("IdProgramIMDB", "= " + IdProgramIMDB);

                // FAKE ID IMDB !!!! <============================================================= A DELETE
                IdProgramIMDB = "tt0407304";

                // Prépare URL TMDB
                url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+ IdProgramIMDB + "?api_key=a9cd33535bcdf6537692b5a25e5ef98e";

                infoProgramTmdb = Api.getInfoMedia(url);
                myJson = new JSONObject(infoProgramTmdb);   
                code = null;
                code = myJson.optString("status_code");

                // Film trouvé sur TMDB sinon on prend les informations de bouygues (code error 6)
                if(code.equals("")) {
                    program = gson.fromJson(infoProgramTmdb, Program.class);    

                    Log.v("runtimeProgram ", "= " + program.getRuntime());
                    Log.v("posterPathProgram ", "= " + program.getposterPath());            

                    found = true;
                }
            }

            nameProgram = "intouchables"; // FAKE Name Program  !!!! <============================================================= A DELETE

            // Récupération Youtube (5 vidéos trailers max)
            url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + nameProgram + "+trailer+movies&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=5&v=2&alt=json";
            trailerYoutube = Api.getInfoMedia(url);

            //feed => {} => entry [] get(1 à 5) => id{} after last :
            // Format Json { ..., "feed":{ ..., "entry":[{..., "id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:17CLlZuiBkQ"}}, {"id":{...}}, {"id":{...}}, {"id":{...}}, {"id":{...}}]}}
            myJson = new JSONObject(trailerYoutube);

            if(!myJson.getJSONObject("feed").optString("entry").equals(""))
            {
                JSONArray dataYoutube = myJson.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
                //nameProgram = myJson.getJSONObject("ListeProgrammes").getJSONArray("Programme").getJSONObject(0).optString("nom");
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                     String[] tag = dataYoutube.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id").optString("$t").split(":");

                    //program.setYoutubeUri(new YoubuteURI(tag[tag.length-1]));             // !!!! <============================================================= A ajoute dans la List Youtube de la classe program !!!!!
                    Log.v("idYoutube","= " + tag[tag.length-1]);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Si pas trouvé ou pas un film, on utilise information de Bouygues
        if(found != true) {
            Log.v("IdProgramIMDB","Not Found => BDD Bouygues");  
            //Log.v("programBouyges","Not Found => BDD Bouygues   " + infoProgramBouygues);
            JSONObject myJson;
             try {
                 Log.v("bbbbbbbbb","= ");
                myJson = new JSONObject(infoProgramBouygues);
                String test = myJson.optString("Programme");
                Log.v("aaaaaaaa","= " + infoProgramBouygues);
                program = gson.fromJson(test, Program.class);               // !!!! <============================================================= Ca ajoute pas dans la classe A VOIR !!!!!


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Log.v("TitleProgram ", "= " + program.getTitle());
        }

        // Utilisation des informations de la chaine + la liste de programme            // !!!! <============================================================= Ca ajoute pas dans la classe A VOIR !!!!!
        canal = gson.fromJson(infoCanal, Canal.class);

        Log.v("NomCanal ", "= " + canal.getName());                                 // !!!! <============================================================= Voir si ca ajoute les valeurs ds la liste des programs!!!!!
    }
    return "youpi";
}
}
```

**Main :**

```
String canalId = msg.getData().getString("message");                                    
currentCanal = new Canal(canalId);
currentProgram = new Program();                 
GetMediaInfo  getMediaInfo = new  GetMediaInfo(handler, currentProgram, currentCanal);
getMediaInfo.execute(NetworkUtils.getUrlHttp(getApplicationContext()));
```

**> EDIT 1 :**

Thank you !

i'm sorry, i'm not really good with Android development, I discovered with my school project.

i can use my class in the Thread UI now !

It was not just to update interface of my app Android but also send the data in my webApp with myWebsocket created in my Thread UI (i created another asynctask to do and interacts with).

The parties :
1 => Subscribe ChannelID between my app and STB (SetTopBox) => Finish => Send handler message with my ID to my Thread UI

2 => Start my WebApp in my STB => Finish => Send handler message OK

3 => Initiate my WebSocket => Finish => Send handler message OK

4 => Get ChannelID WebApp => Finish => Send handler message with ChannelID to my Thread UI

5 => Get Current Canal/Media => Finish => Send handler message with my ID Canal to my Thread UI

6 => Now ! Get Media Info => Send class program to my Thread UI with Interface

7 => So update Interface App and start a last asynctask to send data in my WebApp
And I recall 5/6/7 if there is a new program

After my first asynctask, I call the next in my Handler Thread UI, it's not too heavy for Thread Ui(fragmentActivity) and Handler?? My handler become large.

**> EDIT 2 :** 
I will read Informations about runOnUiThread

Comment: [See this answer about using an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> protected void onPostExecute (String result) {

will be executed on Thread UI, you can safely execute UI changes in there. One common method to inform you Activity of finished AsyncTask is by using Interface. Your activity implements some interface, and passes it to your AsyncTask, which will use this interface to pass results to Activity. This requires you to update this interface reference in AsyncTask during Activity configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact the Thread UI

```
 [your_activity_instance].runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //update here
                            }
                     });
```

Comment: Is that an AsyncTask?

Comment: But I don't quite understand what you want to do @Poldie

Comment: I don't want to do anything, as it's not my question; I'm just wondering what a Runnable has to do with a request for getting an AsyncTask to talk to the thread UI.

Comment: As i indicated above, you should make a call to thread UI

And the way to do this is using the method runOnUiThread of current activity @Poldie