# I Can't use my findViewById from AsyncClass

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview, findviewbyid

I Can't use `findViewById()` from my Kclass=( How can i use it? `

```
private class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //execute - means sending
        response =httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        String str=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.v("Json=", str);
        //adding new response to our Response Class
        resp.addNewResponse(str);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        textView.setText("Done");
    }


  }
}
```

please write an exact code. This class is in another .java file. Not in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Any `View` involving action within your `AsyncTask` is a bad idea, since an `AsyncTask` doesn't have anything to do with views and has different mechanisms on how to communicate with an `Activity`. Use a `Handler` or an `BroadcastReceiver` for that kind of communication.

Comment: @NKN Updating the UI from `onPostExecute` is fine.

Comment: @Simon true! But this is only usable once `doInBackground()` concluded, don't really know what kind of problem is the OP trying to solve...

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to not use `findViewById()` at all since you are in a separate file and that is an `Activity` method.

You can simply use an `interface` to create a `callback` in `onPostExecute()` and send back the `String` result to your `Activity`. Then in your `callback` you can simply set the text as you wish.

[This answer gives an example of using an interface with AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)

Answer (score 0):

You may pass Activity context(YourActivity.this) to your AsyncTask and use `activity.findViewById(...);`

**EDIT**
Some code:

Add to AsyncTask:

```
private Activity mActivity;

public YourAsyncTask(Activity activity){
this.mActivity = activity
}

... 
....

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    if(mActivity!=null){
        TextView textView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
    textView.setText("Done");
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand - look for some Java lessons - you really need them)

Comment: but how can i call my AsyncTask(Activity activity) ??? I called it from another class like - BackGroundTask doItInBackGround = new BackGroundTask();
doItInBackGround.execute();

Comment: what param's i need write here?

Comment: facepalm, http://bit.ly/1lxhnC1 You need to learn some OOP principles & basic Java. Passing a variable is kind of most basic thing

Answer (score 0):

```
private Activity activity;
```

and in constructor:

```
public BackGroundTask(Activity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
}
```

and in post Execute:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    textView.setText("Done");
}
```

If creating new background class from activity class call:

```
BackGroundTask doItInBackGround = new BackGroundTask(this);
```

If in a click listener or any class inside Activity call:

```
BackGroundTask doItInBackGround = new BackGroundTask(ActivityName.this);
```

Comment: declare a property in async task of type activity and from the constructor set it and in post execute use it

Comment: but how can i call my class if i add constructor? i called like   BackGroundTask doItInBackGround = new BackGroundTask();
doItInBackGround.execute();   and how can i call it now?