# How to finish execution of Async Task ?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to finish the execution of an async task before I make some checks for my login.

This is my async task

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) 
    {   
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++){
                    /*allMatrics.add(json_data.getString("matricNos"));
                    allPasswords.add(json_data.getString("password"));*/
                    if (user.equals(json_data.get("matricNos")) && pass.equals(json_data.get("password")))
                    {
                        ok = true;
                        System.out.println("hi i am ok");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Checking ok = "+ ok);
    }
```

I need to finish this async task before I Check its status and then go on for my login authentication. It is supposed to be executed on the onclick of the login button

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                user = uedit.getText().toString();
                pass = pedit.getText().toString();


                if (user.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast error = Toast.makeText(LogInScreen.this, "Enter Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);error.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    final GetMatricNos mat = new GetMatricNos();
                    mat.execute(new ServerConnector());
                    // have to finish task before enter user, have to implement logout as well
                    if ((mat.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))) - This has to be Status.FINISHED
                    {
                        System.out.println(ok);
                        /*  if ((allMatrics.contains(user) && (allPasswords.contains(pass)))) */
                        if (ok)
                        {               
                            Intent homescreen = new Intent(LogInScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                            homescreen.putExtra("username", user);
                            startActivity(homescreen);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogInScreen.this);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#D41E46'>Invalid Login Details</font>"));
                            alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("The login credentials you have entered are invalid. Please try again.")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    }               
                }
            }
        });
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();   
        actionBar.hide();   // To hide the actionBar on LoginScreen
    }
```

Now If I don't finish the task before checking it, it won't let me check the credentials that I am getting from the edit boxes, however first time if I login it doesn't make the check because the task runs when the login button is pressed, but for the second time if I login it goes through...?

Any help would be much appreciated, I tried task.cancel(true) before the check but that doesnt help...

Comment: If your task is a separate file from your `Activity` then [see this answer about using an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) and put the code to run after in your callback method. Otherwise, put the code to run when it finishes in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

If your task needs to finish executing before you do anything else then you must put the code that must wait in your `onPostExecute` which gets called when the task is finished

Comment: The problem is I need the "user" value from the edintext box to pass in `protected JSONArray doInBackground(ServerConnector... params) {
 
   return params[0].GetMatricNos(user);
  }`, so If I do it in onPostExecute I don't pass any value to the query i have in php from here.

Comment: is the asynctask in a separate file? You can always send what you need in the execute method

Comment: No its in the same class

Comment: then just keep a class wide variable and then get it in onPostExecute

Comment: Thanks I've dealt with that, Thanks for the help but there is a little problem @tyczj how do i get it to stop crashing because of this `protected JSONArray doInBackground(ServerConnector... params) {
   if (user.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
   {
    Toast.makeText(LogInScreen.this, "Please Enter Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
   }
   else
   {
    return params[0].GetMatricNos(user);
   }
  }` I have to return something..? it doesn't take null it just crashes

Comment: Cheers for the help guys, I fixed it :)