# Android: Best way to wait for two separate calls to return before continuing

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I've got two separate methods that will return with some data asynchronously, however I want to them collate that information and send it elsewhere as one call.

The way I see it, I could either:

Make the method that submits the data after its recieved wait until it has recieved both sets of information or, quit after x amount of time if it has been waiting.

OR

Make a the methods that receive data call the submit method, if the other data has been received.

Obviously depends upon implementation, but neither of these feel like brilliant solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make the method that submits the data after its recieved wait until it has recieved both sets of information

If this method is on the main thread then don't do this unless absolutely necessary. In which case, you want to show some progress dialog.

> quit after x amount of time if it has been waiting.

Mostly likely you don't want to do this. It stinks of bad design.

> Make a the methods that receive data call the submit method, if the other data has been received.

This you could do and set some flag to know that one is done. What you might want is an `interface`. If you are using an `AsyncTask` for your asynchronous work then [this answer can help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)