# how to call class AsyncTask to another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried to call the "AsyncTask" class from another class called "MainActivity" but "AsyncTask" Class is inside the class called "SiteAdapter". I tried to pass a reference but it not working. How could do that?

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("StackSites", "OnCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Call the class AsyncTask
        new GetAddressTask(this).execute(); // <----ERROR - GetAddressTask cannot be resolved to a type
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask inside SitesAdapter class:**

```
public class SitesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StackSite> { 
    ...//PROCESS

    public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Context mContext;
        public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        //Pass a reference to MainActivity
        private MainActivity mainActivity; // <--- WARNING - The value of the field SitesAdapter.GetAddressTask.mainActivity is not used            
        public GetAddressTask(MainActivity mainActivity)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }                           

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            ...         
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `MainActivity` is not a class that you can not define an object from. It extends `Activity`.

Change your `AsyncTask` class with it;

```
public static class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;
    public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
         super();
         mContext = context;
    }                          

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... values) {
        // If you want to use 'values' string in here
        String values = values[0];        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        ...
    }
}
```

Then call this with it;

```
String values = ""; //You can pass any string value to GetAddressTask with that parameter
//Call the class AsyncTask
new SitesAdapter.GetAddressTask(this).execute(values);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This values where can I use them?

Comment: See my edit @papo . I just changed `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 3):

make `GetAddressTask` static:

```
public static class GetAddressTask
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have a warning in te reference "The value of the field SitesAdapter.GetAddressTask.mainActivity is not used" and a error in in calling the class "GetAddressTask cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: seems that GetAddressTask is not imported

Comment: if you don't use MainActivity in your AsyncTask then simply remove this field and a constructor as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this is working for me.

Just create a method in your `SitesAdapter` class and call it from your `MainActivity` like this :

```
new SitesAdapter().start(MainActivity.this);
```

now in your `SitesAdapter` class do this :

```
private Context mContext;
public void start(){
   mContext = context;
   new GetAddressTask().execute();
}
```

May this help you

Answer (score 0):

You could make it `static` then call it with

```
SitesAdapter.GetAddressTask myClass = new SitesAdapter.GetAddressTask();
myClass.execute();
```

But, if you are going to be needing this in multiple activities, then it is probably worth it to take it out of that class and put it in its own file.

If you will need to update your UI from the task, you can [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) on using an `interface` with a callback to your calling `Activity`.