# Calling method from another class in onPostExecute causing nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

This might help someone also: [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

I am calling method from another class in `onPostExecute()`.

I assume that `onPostExecute()` is called after `doInBackground(String... params)` and that is right, according to documentation and debugger.

Calling the method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    CreateHangOut crtHO = new CreateHangOut();
    crtHO.createHangOut(result);
}
```

Part of method called, causing NPE (first line of method):

```
public void createHangOut(String location) {
    String city=autocompleteTV.getText().toString();
   }
```

Autocomplete `TextView`(`autocompleteTV`) is initialized onCreate of the activity.

Here is how I call `AsyncTask`:

```
create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new 
HTTPRequest().execute((autocompleteTV.getText()).toString());
            }
    });
```

Method called onCreate (of activity from where button is clicked) :

```
private void initialize() {
    gAPI= new GoogleAPIAutocomplete();
    autocompleteTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.crtHOLocOptionsTV);
    setUpAutocomplete();
    create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.crtHOCreateBtn);
    name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.crtHONameET);
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new 
    HTTPRequest().execute((autocompleteTV.getText()).toString());
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably `autocompleteTV` is `null`. How you are accessing `autocompleteTV` in `CreateHangOut` class?

Comment: Does `autocompleteTv` have any text in it?

Comment: I think you are right, it might be null because autocompleteTV is initialized only onCreate, but why is it losing its initialization when I call AsyncTask? Please answer me this and I will mark it as right.

Comment: @OndrejTokar : `why is it losing its initialization when I call AsyncTask` depend on how you are accessing in `CreateHangOut`

Comment: `public void createHangOut(String location) {` is in a separate class from your `Activity`? If so, how do you get a reference to it in that class? Also, do you call `setContentView()` before calling `initialize()`?

Comment: Ahaa so if I access it like this: 
`CreateHangOut crtHO = new CreateHangOut();`
 `crtHO.createHangOut(result);`
Then it is creating new object so thats why. Please answer it :) Thank you.

Comment: `createHangOut(String location)` is in the same class as the Activity is. I am just calling it from `AsyncTask`

Comment: So `crtHO` is your `Activity`? You don't usually (probably ever) want to initialize an `Activity` that way. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) on updating your activity from AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `createHangOut` method is in `CreateHangOut` Activity so no need to create new object for accessing method just call it using method name if class which extends `AsyncTask` class is inner class of `CreateHangOut` :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    CreateHangOut.this.createHangOut(result);
}
```

Comment: What should I do if that `AsyncTask` is in another class? Should I make method `createHangOut(String result)` static then? But it causes another issues. Any good solution for that matter?

Comment: @OndrejTokar: if  `AsyncTask` is in other class then instead of calling method of Activity send TextView initialized instance to class which is extending `AsyncTask` using class constructor