# Dismiss dialog in AsyncTask from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the `MainActivity`, I have an `AsyncTask` in which a `ProgressDialog` is displayed, starting in `onPreExecute()` . If the processing in the `doInBackground()` crashes, then I get this exception:
*Activity us.nm.state.mmd.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView*

I believe it is occurring because the dialog is still being displayed while the activity is going down. The examples of AsyncTask/Progress dialog I see all have the dialog within the`AsyncTask` class.
  I would like to try dismissing the dialog in the Activity.onPause() method (as below), but since the dialog in declared in `AsyncTask` class, `MainActivity` does have access to it.

I moved the instantiation of the dialog to `MainActivity`. So `onPause()` does get the called and the call to `dismiss()` happens, but this is long after the message "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" appears on the device.

How do I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         nDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);
        nDialog.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.loading));
         nDialog.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.loading));
         nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         nDialog.setCancelable(false);

         String url = "http://----------------------------------------";
        Fragment myFragment = mTabsPageAdapter.getItem(TabsPagerAdapter.MY_TAB);
        new LoadAndStoreDataTask((OnLoadAndStoreCompleteListener)permitsFragment, nDialog).execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(nDialog != null)
            nDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class LoadAndStoreDataTask extends AsyncTask   <String,  Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Resources resources = getResources();

         nDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       if (nDialog != null) {
            nDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
    if (nDialog != null) {
        nDialog.dismiss();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Is the task class an inner class of the Activity?

Comment: Yes, the `AsyncTask` is a class within `MainActivity`. I should have specified that.

Comment: Yeah, then use Petey's answer

Comment: Would it be possible if the `AsyncTask` class were not inside the `MainActivity` class?

Comment: Sure. By either getting a reference to the Dialog from the task or create a callback and use the activity variable. [Here is an example of the interface option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648?s=7|0.3001#18517648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
private class LoadAndStoreDataTask extends AsyncTask   <String,  Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
```

to

```
private class LoadAndStoreDataTask extends AsyncTask   <String,  Integer, String> {
```

so the task will used the MainActivity nDialog field instead of the one in the LoadAndStoreDataTask class

Comment: This does prevent the leak. As I said, all the examples I see have the `ProgressDialog` with the `AsycTask`. Does having it outside of the `AsyncTask` violate some best practices?

Comment: yea,  its prevented by the asynctask not having the nDialog field and also your activity's `onPause` where you dismiss it.  Looking at this again, It would be advisable to set nDialog to null right after the dismiss call and re-create it again whnever you run LoadAndStoreDataTask