# Proper way to subclass a Java AsyncTask for looser coupling

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, subclass

What is the proper way to subclass an `AsyncTask` so that it can be reused in multiple activities?

I have a multiple Activities that all use the same `AsyncTask` to get some JSON data. The only difference is that each Activity has it's own `ProgressBar` to show activty and its own *processResult* for processing the returned JSON data. I would like to subclass the `AsyncTask` so that I can pass in a reference to a `ProgressBar` so the appropriate Activity's ProgressBar's visibility is set and pass the returned data to that Activity's *processResults()*.

**Here is an abstract of a typical activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar mProgessBar;
    private List<Object> myList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);


        mProgessBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProgessBar);
        myList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        getData();

    }

    private void getData() {
        //All async tasks take string variables
            new BGGetData().execute("Something", "Something", "Dark side", null);
    }

    private void processResults(JSONObject data) {
    //Different types of data for different activities.
        //process JSON results to fill myList or do something other action with the data
    }


    ///////
    //BACKGROUND TASK IS REPEATED IN MULTIPLE ACTIVITIES
    ///////
    public class BGGetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            // do something to get a jsonobject

            return json; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject data) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            processResults(data);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The linked answer shows that you can pass other values to the constructor so just pass your progress dialog there and whatever else you need.

Comment: @codeMagic The question you linked to doesn't show how to call the processResults for the calling activity.

Comment: [This one does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask) use a common interface to implement in the task class that you create. That one has an example with a link to another example.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! @codeMagic you can delete this question if you want.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to delete. It will help future users with the same issue to find the answers.